# Debugging @Lock in Spring Data JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, logging, spring-data-jpa, locking

In Spring Data JPA, when I use `@NamedQueries` with `lockMode = LockModeType.WRITE`, I can see the results in the logs (assuming `jpa.show-sql` is `true`):

```
... SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
```

However, when I use `@Lock(LockModeType.WRITE)` annotation on a method, I don't see anything in the logs. I want to make sure that the locking mechanism is working as expected.

> How can I see that `@Lock(LockModeType.WRITE)` is working? What log level should be enabled?

---

**EDIT:** Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Transactional
    public User checkCredentials(String email, String password, String verificationCode)
            throws BadCredentialsException {

        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if(user == null)
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username");

        ...

        user.setLastVerificationCode(verificationCode);
        userRepository.save(user);

        return user;
    }
}
```

Comment: To make sure: you have set this annotation to a query method in a JpaRepository?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: I set `@Lock` on a method in a JpaRepository. Separately, I also tried setting it on a method in a `@Service` which used the repository (just out of curiosity).

Comment: And do you have @Transacational on the service?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Yes; please see the edited question. I added an excerpt of my code. It actually tries to authenticate a user by his email, (regular) password, and a verification code. If everything is OK, the last verification code is set in the DB. I want to lock the row corresponding to a user, so that no two threads (transactions) read and write it concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong `LockModeType`: `LockModeType.WRITE` is a synonym for `LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_IMCREMENT`

```
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
```

And you can remove the `@Lock` from your **service** method, because `@Lock` only works on **repository** methods. It is also important to add `@Transactional` to corresponding **service** methods.

Read more about `LockModes` here

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. For future reference, here's the documentation of `LockModeType` from Java EE 8: https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html